# Need an rpm of make and gcc for Redhat version 4

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel4

I'm working on an issue on our Redhat v4 server. I know, it's very old. There is no yum, gcc, make, etc. I need gcc and make. I found gcc source code in tar.gz format. However, I can't find an rpm of make. I spent whole afternoon today searching the web with no luck.

I also searched the web for gcc 4.1.2 rpm but there are so many links and I'm not sure which one would be the best match or most compatible.

Comment: Use the one that your RHN subscription makes available.

Comment: there's totally make and gcc rpms available http://vault.centos.org/4.9/os/ia64/CentOS/RPMS/

Comment: will that work for redhat?

Comment: CentOs is compatible with RedHat so yes - this should work on RHEL if it works on CentOs

Comment: Did @thrig 's answer work?

Comment: I went for a different route because I'm now cross compiling the software I need in our redhat server on a different and much more powerful computer. The compiled binary worked. I'm now cross compiling openssl but encountering issues.